# Table/Figures caption numbers are automatically based on Chapter/Section instead of the number of actual tables/figures

Tags: longtable, overleaf, overleaf-toolkit

I have used the following Overleaf Template for my Master Thesis: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/hvl-master-thesis-software-engineering-template/qjtzwnzvhrys

However, after inserting a figure and table, I noticed that they are numbered based on the section they are in. Not on the number of tables/figures. The screenshot below shows the table (which is the first in my paper, thus should have been Table 1: xxxx).

[image]

```
  %--------------------------------------
% Master's Thesis Title Page 
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (23/05/14)
% Thanks to Magnus Marthinsen, this thesis and template is made available for Master studentes at HVL Joint SE program (01.03.2021)
%---------------------------------------

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for box manipulation
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip} % Used to create spaces between paragraphs
\usepackage{dirtytalk} % quotes by talk
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}  % Used to add a wordlist/glossaries
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%zelf toegevoegd
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow} %table
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pifont} %%%bullet points
\usepackage{longtable}


%BIB by Adrian
%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric, urldate=long]{biblatex}
\usepackage{multibib}
% See the references.bib file. Most Bibtex bibliographies in Computer Science can be found from dblp.org 
%\addbibresource{references.bib}




% Glossary/wordlist
\makeglossaries
\input{glossaries.tex}

\begin{document}

%
% COLORS USED THROUGH THE REPORT
%
\definecolor{kb_red}{RGB}{96,2,4}
\definecolor{light_gray}{RGB}{160,160,160}
\definecolor{med_gray}{RGB}{96,94,94}
\definecolor{black}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{white}{RGB}{155,155,155}
\definecolor{light_green}{RGB}{208,240,192}
\definecolor{light_red}{RGB}{255,204,203}

% CODE STYLE
\definecolor{javared}{rgb}{0.6,0,0} % for strings
\definecolor{javagreen}{rgb}{0.25,0.5,0.35} % comments
\definecolor{javapurple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.35} % keywords
\definecolor{javadocblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.35,0.75} % javadoc
 
\makeatletter
\lst@Key{matchrangestart}{f}{\lstKV@SetIf{#1}\lst@ifmatchrangestart}
\def\lst@SkipToFirst{%
    \lst@ifmatchrangestart\c@lstnumber=\numexpr-1+\lst@firstline\fi
    \ifnum \lst@lineno<\lst@firstline
        \def\lst@next{\lst@BeginDropInput\lst@Pmode
        \lst@Let{13}\lst@MSkipToFirst
        \lst@Let{10}\lst@MSkipToFirst}%
        \expandafter\lst@next
    \else
        \expandafter\lst@BOLGobble
    \fi}
\makeatother
 
\lstset{language=Java,
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
keywordstyle=\color{javapurple}\bfseries,
stringstyle=\color{javared},
commentstyle=\color{javagreen},
morecomment=[s][\color{javadocblue}]{/**}{*/},
numbers=left,
captionpos=b,
frame=single,
breakatwhitespace=false,
breaklines=true,
numberstyle=\tiny\color{black},
stepnumber=1,
numbersep=10pt,
tabsize=2,
showspaces=false,
showstringspaces=false,
matchrangestart=t}

%Title page
\input{title_page.tex}
\titlePage
\pagebreak

%author page
\input{author_page.tex}
\authorPage
\pagebreak

\section*{Abstract}
\textbf{[Title]}, \textbf{[Introduction]}, \textbf{[Objectives]}, \textbf{[Methods]}, \textbf{[Results]}, \textbf{[Conclusion]}
\\ \\
\textbf{Keywords:}
%\acrlong{MDSE} is a ...

\section*{Acknowledgements}
First and foremost, I would like to thank ...
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\printglossary[nonumberlist]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]


\input{Chapters/1.Introduction.tex}
\input{Chapters/2.Literature.tex}
\input{Chapters/3.ResearchMethod.tex}


\appendix
%\input{appendix/1.Systematic Literature}
%\input{appendix/2.Interview}



\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
\bibliography{references}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}  %%%%ADD BIB TO TABLE OF CONTENTS
%\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
%\bibliography{references}
%\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: What you see is standard. In classes with `chapter` one normally number as `chapter.figure` etc. If you only use `figure`, then it is hard for the reader to find the figure as one has no indication which chapter it is on. So I'd suggest leaving this as it is.

Comment: @daleif Ah okay, I was just a bit confused because I have never encountered this before (I live in the Netherlands, perhaps we count differently). But then again, we do use international templates (who also count from 1 etc.). If I do need to change it, would you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: If your're using a modern latex engine `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` and similar for `table` ought to do it.

Comment: If it is confusing to number tables and sections the same way, try `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter\Alph{table}}` etc.  Then again, this is a thesis and the format may be required.

Comment: thank you both very much!